# How do I convert poles and zeros of a transfer function into a circuit / required circuit components?

Tags: transfer-function, active-filter

I have been given a Bode plot of a low pass filter, and tasked with essentially reversing the effects by using a high pass filter. I have solved for the transfer function which is the first equation, and I am assuming the inverse transfer function will give me the information I need to construct the high pass filter.

I know the values for \$z\$ and \$p\$.

Is there a method given any transfer function to realise the circuit elements required?

$$H(s) = 0.17\frac{s-z}{s-p}$$
$$H(s)^{-1} = 5.88\frac{s-p}{s-z}$$

Comment: I cannot help with the transfer function, however you don't exactly get a free lunch, you need an amplifier with gain. e.g. an active high pass, to get close to cancelling it out, just as the low pass starts to attenuate more than your hoping to compensate, the high pass needs a gain a hair more than 1, moving up until the low pass has reduced it to near 0, and you hit your op amps gain / bandwidth limit,

Comment: *Is there a method given any transfer function to realise the circuit elements required?* Yes there is, I followed a course on this at Uni. back in the 1990s. So unfortunately I forgot what book we used. But you cannot implement **any** transfer function, some are impossible. There are methods to determine if a network can be made or not. If it can then a certain procedure is followed. Search for "network synthesis" and maybe you find a lead.

Comment: The formula for H(s) isn't the TF for a low pass filter or a high pass filter. As you should be able to see, when s = p, H(s) becomes infinity hence, it is a bandpass filter with infinite Q.

Comment: What are the values of Z and P?

Comment: Z = 770 hz   P=132 hz

Comment: You should first rewrite the expression in a *low-entropy* format: \$H(s)=H_0\frac{1+\frac{s}{\omega_z}}{1+\frac{s}{\omega_p}}\$. \$H_0\$ is the gain/attenuation you want while you will see the zero and pole values organized in the way \$N(s)=1+\frac{s}{\omega_z}\$ and \$D(s)=1+\frac{s}{\omega_p}\$. However, are you sure of the minus signs?